# Find count of concurrent items

Tags: excel-formula

I have parallel execution of 48 entries and I would like to make a diagram on how many thread Parallel.ForEach ran for me at every time.

I made the debug output seen below, where adjacent start/end lines are from the same thread. For quick result, I went into Excel and put them into column A:

```
A
61771961 ParallEx starts
61773115 ParallEx ends
61771961 ParallEx starts
61773271 ParallEx ends
61771961 ParallEx starts
61773287 ParallEx ends
61771961 ParallEx starts
61773318 ParallEx ends
```

Now I used `=VALUE(MID(A1; 1; 8))` to get value pairs of the form:

```
B           C
61771961    61773115

61771961    61773271

61771961    61773287

61771961    61773318

...
```

Then I made into column D the numbers 1..96, and used `=SMALL(B$1:C$96;D1)` to get the ordered list of time points at which changes to any thread occurred:

```
D   E
1   61771961
2   61771961
3   61771961
4   61771961
5   61772507
6   61773037
7   61773115
8   61773115
9   ...
```

Then I wanted to find how many threads I had running at every of the interesting time points:

```
=SUMIFS(B$1:B$96;CONCATENATE(">=";E1);C$1:C$96;CONCATENATE("<=";E1))
```

but the result is always zero. Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values in Column C are all Greater than your values in Column E per your examples.

Column C: 61773115   Column E: 61771961 
Your sumifs is looking for column be to be less than or equal to Column E which should work fine, but it is also looking for column C to be less than Column E which it is not finding

Hope that helps